# python-style function list input for c++

Tags: c++, list

I want to have an input to a function similar to python so that then I can loop over it in inside the function. But I am not sure how I should define the input.

```
func(["a","b","c"])
```

so that it can also be called

```
func(["a","b","c", "d"])
```

is there actually such style of input in c++?
I'd be glad if someone also suggested a way of looping over it since my c++ experience is quite basic.

-------edit,

will be glad if this "[]" style of brackets are possible instead of "{}" similar to python and with minimal code.

Comment: Is the given list supposed to contain only `char` or string values ?

Comment: @Fareanor they would be of type std::srting

Comment: `[]` is not possible, by using `{}` you make an initializer list that constructs either the vector as suggested in my answer or gets passed to the function by itself.

Comment: @Alipapa: Note that the string literals you're using are just plain `const char[2]` literals, not `std::string`. You'll [need to add an `s` suffix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator""s)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) to do that:

```
#include <initializer_list>

template<class T>
void func(std::initializer_list<T> il) {
  for (auto x : il);
}

int main() {
  func({"a","b","c"});
  func({"a","b","c", "d"});
}
```

> will be glad if this "[]" style of brackets are possible instead of
> "{}" similar to python and with minimal code.

Unfortunately, the multidimensional subscript operator only works in C++23, see [p2128](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2128r6.pdf) for more details.

Comment: interesting proposal, but I dont see how that would help with `func( ["a","b","c"])`. You'd still need an object on wich you can call the operator

Comment: But you can do something like `func(list["a","b","c"])`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 But If OP complains about having `{}` instead of `[]`, I'm pretty sure the same complaint will go for using an object `list` to call the subscript operator on :p

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) for that purpose.

The function may be defined as follows:

```
void func(std::initializer_list<std::string> il)
{
   for(const std::string & s : il)
   {
       // ...
   }
}
```

And you may use it the following way:

```
int main()
{
    func({"a", "b", "c"});

    return 0;
}
```

---

> will be glad if this "[]" style of brackets are possible instead of "{}" similar to python and with minimal code.

Python and C++ are not the same languages and symbols, keywords, etc... have their own meaning. In Python, `[]` means a list, but in C++ it is the subscript operator (supposed to be called for a given object), which is a completely different thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`std::initilializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

void foo(std::initializer_list<std::string> l){
    for (const auto& s : l) std::cout << s << " ";
}

int main() {
    foo({"a","b","c"});
}
```

I think python does not distinguish between character and string literals, but C++ does. `"a"` is a string literal, while `'a'` is a character literal. If you actually wanted characters you can use a `std::initializer_list<char>`. You can also consider to simply pass a `std::string` to the function (`foo("abc")`).

> will be glad if this "[]" style of brackets are possible instead of "{}" similar to python and with minimal code.

Better get used to different languages being different. Trying to make code in one language look like a different language usually does not pay off, because not only in details python and C++ are very different.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers will work but I think your looking for `std::vector`, which is a array that can dynamically grow and shrink. It is basically the c++ equivalent to a python list (except you can only store on data type in it).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void foo (std::vector<std::string> vec)
{
    // normal for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size (); i++)
    {
      std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl; // do something 
    }
    std::cout << "#########" << std::endl;


    // range based for loop
    for (auto val : vec)
    {
      std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "#########" << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
  foo ({'a', 'b', 'c'});
  foo ({'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'});
}
```

replace `std::string` with the data type that you need.

[live example](https://onlinegdb.com/7HTKp55M2)

Comment: Using a `std::vector` is overkill, and in `main()` you are still calling your function with an `std::initializer_list` as argument anyway just to construct a useless `std::vector` afterwards. It's extra work for no reason (OP just want to loop over the given range).

Comment: As far as I know `std::initializer_list` is thought for constructors and it might be a little confusing for a beginner to use such an uncommon thing.

Comment: A beginner will stay a beginner forever if one reasons like that :) Moreover, constructing a `std::vector` when it's not necessary is a waste. This is the reason why `std::initializer_list` exist. The best way to teach a "beginner" is to teach him how to use the proper structures for the proper reasons, not to comfort him with what is a mistake just because he's a "beginner".

Comment: Your right, I've been programing in c++ for about 5 years and have only recently heard of `std::initializer_list` because nobody told me how I could optimize my code by using it.

Comment: Well, we all have still (a lot of) things to learn ^^